# Using realloc on a previously malloc-ed pointer causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

i have problem with C, this code throw stack dump. I don't have idea whats wrong.

```
char *text;
text = (char *) malloc(sizeof (char));
int size = 1;
char c = 'a';
char *new;
while (1) {
    c = getchar();
    putchar(c);
    if (c == 10) {
        text[size - 1] = '\0';
        break;
    }
    text[size - 1] = c;
    size++;
    new = (char *) realloc(text, size * sizeof (*new));
    free(text);
    text = new;
}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: remove `free(text);`, that is wrong and not required, `realloc()` takes care.

Comment: Case of reading the man page here.

Comment: `sizeof (*new)` - the type `char` is size `1`, by definition.

Comment: remove the free or change the realloc to a malloc, although realloc is expressly designed for doing this

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you pass `text` as the first argument to `realloc()` and later, without checking for failure, you pass the same to `free()`. That is what is causing the issue here.

As per `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5

> The `realloc` function deallocates the old object pointed to by `ptr` and returns a
>   pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size. [...] If memory for the new object cannot be
>   allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.

So, if the `realloc()` is success, afterwards, calling

```
free(text);
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You need not to bother about `text` anymore, remove the call to `free()`.

Related, for `free()`, §7.22.3.3

> [...] Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the
>   behavior is undefined.

**TL;DR** First check for the success of `realloc()`, if success, don't touch `text`, if `realloc()` fails, then you need to call `free(text);`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't free the pointer `text` because upon success `realloc()` deallocates the old pointer.

From C11 standard chapter 7.22.3.5 The realloc function:

> The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr and returns a
>   pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size. The contents of the new
>   object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of
>   the new and old sizes. Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object have
>   indeterminate values.